# How to password protect a register form for new hires

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, middleware

I would like to have an admin registration form available only to new hires who need to make their new employee account. Best thoughts on strategies or common practice for this scenario?

Working with Express Middleware in Node.js.

Comment: Give access with a temporary ID allocated to each hire. Once the hire is successfully registered the employee account, the temporary ID access can be revoked.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you only want to allow some people to register, don't make a public registration feature.

Instead, create a 'invite user' feature. You can send a secret link to their email address, and only the recipient gets this link, can follow the link and complete their registration.